# Swift: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement

Tags: swift, swift5, hashable

I'm having this issue in my Swift project:

> 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'ActiveType' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead

```
struct Payment: Hashable {
    let product: SKProduct
    let quantity: Int
    let atomically: Bool
    let applicationUsername: String
    let simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox: Bool
    let callback: (TransactionResult) -> Void

    var hashValue: Int {
        return product.productIdentifier.hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: Payment, rhs: Payment) -> Bool {
        return lhs.product.productIdentifier == rhs.product.productIdentifier
    }
}
```

I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395207/swift-hashable-hashvalue-is-deprecated-as-a-protocol-requirement) approach, but didn't have any success.

[Swift Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD8sw.png)

Comment: Remove your `callback` property and add a `success` property `var success: Bool`. Btw `hashValue` is deprecated `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(product.productIdentifier) `

Comment: Thank you! This `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(product.productIdentifier) }` fixed the issue.